# Removing duplicates of a 2D array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I have found lots of methods to remove duplicates of a 1D array but could not find a 2D example. 
In addition to that, I wonder if the fuction can "leave" an instance of the duplicate item instead of removing them all.

Is it possible to do it?

Example:

```
Sub Tests()

Dim Example()

Example(0,0) = "Apple"
Example(1,0) = "Apple"
Example(0,1) = "Pear"
Example(1,1) = "Orange"

End Sub
```

Remaining items would be: `Apple, Pear and Orange`

Comment: When you say duplicates do you mean the entire row is the same or just ay duplicate at all? If the row or column doesn't have to be the same then why are you using a 2d array for this data?

Comment: Because they correspond to each other, it is like  Array(Apple, redcolor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I like to do it, using a separate array to hold the unique items. This prevents your loops from having to cycle through non unique items when trying to test them.

```
Sub Test()

Dim Example(1, 1) As String
Dim NoDups() As String
Dim I, II, III As Long

ReDim NoDups(UBound(Example, 1) * UBound(Example, 2))

For I = 0 To UBound(Example, 1)
    For II = 0 To UBound(Example, 2)
        For III = 0 To UBound(NoDups)
            If NoDups(III) = Example(I, II) Then
                Exit For
            ElseIf NoDups(III) = "" Then
                NoDups(III) = Example(I, II)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To work through a 2D array, do as you would with a 1D array, but with a 'width' loop inside of a 'height' loop.

ie:

```
for a = 1 to number_of_elements_in_first_dimension
    for y = 1 to number_of_elements_in_second_dimension
        initial_comparison_string = array(a,b)
        for x = a to number_of_elements_in_first_dimension
            for y = b + 1 to number_of_elements_in_second_dimension
                if Initial_comparison_string = array(x,y) then array(x,y) = ""
            next y
        next x

    next b
next a
```

This will run fairly slowly with a very large 2D array, but I think you'd have to do 2 nested loops like this to take each value and compare it against each value which appears later.